# Overlay with translucent background, but text full opacity

Tags: html, css

How would I do the following:

```
.accept-overlay {
    width: 1120px;
    height: 518px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(249, 180, 145);
    opacity: 0.3;
    border-radius: 4px;
}

<div class="accept-overlay">
    <span class="regular-opacity">Click Accept to View</span>
</div>
```

Basically, I want the overlay to have an opacity of 0.30, but the text itself, "Click Accept to View" should be normal black text. How would I accomplish this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use rgba()

```css
.accept-overlay {
    width: 1120px;
    height: 518px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgba(249, 180, 145,0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

```html
<div class="accept-overlay">
    <span class="regular-opacity">Click Accept to View</span>
</div>
```

Answer (score 4):

You can't use opacity since it will change the opacity of the element and all of it's children.

Instead you could try using rgba for the background color.

```
.accept-overlay {
    width: 1120px;
    height: 518px;
    position: absolute;
    background: rgb(249, 180, 145, 0.3);
    border-radius: 4px;
}
```